# problem in address of one user

Tags: scripts

hi

i want to do these jobs by one scripts:

1- read the name of current user (I don't know what is it!)

2- switch to root user

3- go to root directory

4- go to the desktop director of first user

I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
_user=id -u -n
su
cd
cd ..
cd ~"$_user"
```

but it does'n switch the directory 
I also made password for root user,before run this scripts

any help!

Thanks,

Babak

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in last line of the script!

Change the line to

`cd /home/$_user/Desktop`

This should work!